# how to register my UART putc or puts function for use with standard library printf() function?

Tags: console, printf, beagleboneblack, bare-metal

I am writing a bare metal program for my beaglebone. So I use UART0 for my serial debug messages. I have made a custom function called

```
uart0_putc(const char c);
```

and

```
uart0_puts(const char *str);
```

which would output the character or string to uart0 which I am able to see in my terminal window.

Sourcery-Codebench from mentor graphics is the compiler suite I am using here which provides standard C-libraries with printf(). Now what I want is to hook up my uart0_putc and uart0_puts so that i can use provided printf() for getting formatted messages on my terminal.

Anyone can tell me is this feasible? and how to do the same?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am using this compiler here - Link missing bro

Comment: I meant that I am using Sourcery Codebench Lite or as it earlier used to be called CodeSourcery from Mentor graphics as my compiler suite for the job.